# Er : Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement Visual Basic 2017 using MC Access 2016 , oleDb 4.0

Tags: vb.net, oledb

I am trying to insert data in my access database but i am getting a `Syntax error in INSERT statemnt` exception.Can someone please help me troubleshoot this error...Maybe my inset statement is not correct ?

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Try
        If cmbTo.Text = "" Or cmbfrom.Text = "" Or cmbDay.Text = "" Or cmbMonth.Text = "" Or cmbYear.Text = "" Or cmbListBus.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please Insert Your Destination")
        Else
            Dim conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Hacke\source\repos\Student\Database\studentdatabase.mdb")
            Dim insert As String = "INSERT INTO [BUSTICKET] VALUE ('" & cmbfrom.Text & "','" & cmbTo.Text & "','" & cmbDay.Text & "','" & cmbMonth.Text & "','" & cmbYear.Text & "','" & cmbListBus.Text & "');"


            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(insert, conn)
            conn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Success")
            conn.Close()


        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Err : " & Err.Description)
    End Try
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: The first thing to do is not use any string concatenation when building your SQL statement, look at how I use parameters in a code sample in the link below which targets a newer version of ms-access yet the version of access does not matter. Next up, when using a try/catch use ex.Message instead of Err.Description.

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CRUD-data-operations-for-4783d8dd?redir=0

Comment: As far as i see,you are using a wrong `INSERT STATEMENT`..In your insert statement,you haven't defined which table you are inserting in.Moreover,if i consider `[BUSTICKET]` to be the table,then you are not defining the columns but trying to set the values which will not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few mistakes in your post has made it a bit difficult for us to understand.Anyway,i've submitted an edit of your post.

The problem i see so far is that you haven't defined which table you want to insert the data in.For example,if your table name is `Students` ,then a sample sql/OleDb statement might look like

```
"Seletct * from Students",ConnectionString
```

**Note :** In the following statement,i used (*) which means i am not selecting/targeting any particular column/cell but all the columns/cells.This statement is used for various purposes specially when retrieving data from the database.

However,your motive is to insert data in the database.

The `INSERT` statement for any database software(AFAIK) must include the `Table` name you are targeting,the `Column/Cell` headers/names.Let's assume your `Table` name is `Students` and you want to insert data in `FirstName`,`LastNmae` columns.Then a sample `Insert` statement may look like :

```
"Insert into Students(FirstName,LastName)values(@fname,@lname)", ConnectionString
```

Now,**NOTE THAT** i am not adding the values directly in the statement.you can do that if you want.However,in this sample insert statement,i am rather defining some parameter names like`@Fname` and `@Lname`.This will be used later on to finally insert data into the table's columns.

Now,if you go with my sample code,you must assign some values to these parameters from your application.We have 2 parameters now and they are `@Fname` and `@Lname`.We now need to add literal values to them.Let's assume the values are coming from `TextBox`es.

```
MyOledbCommand.Add("@Fname",OledbDatatype.VarChar).Value = FNameTxtBox.Text

'Or you can use :

MyOledbCommand.AddWithValue("@Fname",FNameTxtBox.Text)
```

After you are done assigning the textboxes(or some string or whatever) as the values,it is time to execute the command so that the data inserts.For that,we generally call :

```
MyOleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

So,here's a full sample :

```
Dim con as New oleDbConnection = "ConnectionStringHere"
Con.open
Dim MyOleDbCommand as new OleDbCommand("Insert into Students(FirstName,LastName)values(@fname,@lname)", con)
MyOledbCommand.AddWithValue("@Fname",FNameTxtBox.Text)
MyOledbCommand.AddWithValue("@Lname",LNameTxtBox.Text)
MyOleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery
Con.Close
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: "keywords are reserved, which means that you cannot use them as names for programming elements such as variables or procedures" from MS docs. As one of our top contributors says "Words have meanings. Those are parameter names.

Comment: I think BUSTICKET is the name of the table